# How to get values from this parameters

Tags: c#, xml

can someone help me with this xml? How i can get the value `hodnota` from for eg. attribute named `PC0.1`

```
<items>
  <item kod_zbozi="1010113414">
    <Parametr kod_parametru="PC0.1" hodnota="AutoCont Allegro" />
    <Parametr kod_parametru="PC4.2" hodnota="Windows 10 Pro" />
  </item>
  <item kod_zbozi="1011124131">
    <Parametr kod_parametru="PC0.1" hodnota="AutoCont OfficePro" />
    <Parametr kod_parametru="PC4.2" hodnota="Windows 10 Pro" />
  </item>
  <item kod_zbozi="1011124135">
    <Parametr kod_parametru="PC0.1" hodnota="AutoCont OfficePro" />
    <Parametr kod_parametru="PC4.2" hodnota="Windows 10 Pro" />
  </item>
  <item kod_zbozi="1011124139">
    <Parametr kod_parametru="PC0.1" hodnota="AutoCont OfficePro" />
    <Parametr kod_parametru="PC4.2" hodnota="Windows 11 Pro" />
  </item>
  <item kod_zbozi="1011124145">
    <Parametr kod_parametru="PC0.1" hodnota="AutoCont OfficePro" />
    <Parametr kod_parametru="PC4.2" hodnota="Windows 10 Pro" />
  </item>
  <item kod_zbozi="1011340128">
    <Parametr kod_parametru="PC0.1" hodnota="AutoCont OfficePro" />
    <Parametr kod_parametru="PC4.2" hodnota="Windows 10 Pro" />
  </item>
</items>
```

thank you

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck? *"I want to do X, tell me how"* is not a question for SO. If you don't know how to read XML learn. Make you best attempt to achieve your aim and, if what you do doesn't work, then you've got a question to ask here.

Answer (score 0):

Assume this xml string is `xmlData`, you can get the `output` like this

```
using System.Xml;

// ..

var output = new List<string>();

var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlData);
var nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("items/item/Parametr");
if (nodes != null)
    foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
    {
        if (node.Attributes != null
            && node.Attributes["kod_parametru"]?.InnerText == "PC0.1"
            && node.Attributes["hodnota"] != null)
            result.Add(node.Attributes["hodnota"].InnerText);
    }

// output is ready (count = 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution give all the parameters

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            List<Item> items = doc.Descendants("item")
                .Select(x => new Item()
                {
                    zbozi = (string)x.Attribute("kod_zbozi"),
                    parameters = x.Elements("Parametr").Select(y => new Parameter() {  parametru = (string)y.Attribute("kod_parametru"),  hodnota = (string)y.Attribute("hodnota") }).ToList()
                }).ToList();

            var results = items
                .Select(x => new { zbozi = x.zbozi, parameter = x.parameters.Where(y => y.parametru == "PC0.1").FirstOrDefault() })
                .Where(x => x.parameter != null)
                .Select(x => new { zbozi = x.zbozi, parametru = x.parameter.parametru, hodnota = x.parameter.hodnota })
                .ToList();
        }
    }
    public class Item
    {
        public string zbozi { get; set; }
        public List<Parameter> parameters { get; set; }

    }
    public class Parameter
    {
        public string parametru { get; set; }
        public string hodnota { get; set; }
    }


 
}
```